# How To play pre-recorded audio to make character seem talking in unity 3D , and have Audio Player Callback to cheack if the sound is done playing

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

### Unity 3D Audio Play from Pre-Recorded Audio File To Make Game Characters Seem Talking In the Game

hello everyone, I am working on unity game where the character listens to some voice from another character in the Game. the Audio is from Previously recorded and stored as Asset file. 
but the problem is I have no way of checking the voice is done playing to continue to other actions.
can anyone Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found A Way To Do That

```
//Declare the approprate files
public AudioClip soundFile;
AudioSource mySound;


void Awake(){
    mySound = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
}

public bool isPlaying(AudioClip clip){
    if((Time.time - startTime) >= clip.length){
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

Thren You can Use The Speak Function as

```
void Speak_func(){
        mySound.PlayOneShot (soundFile, 0.7F);
        startTime = Time.time;

    if (!isPlaying (soundFile)) {
        //what ever you want to do when speaking is done
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You check if audio is done playing with [`AudioSource.isPlaying`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource-isPlaying.html)

As for playing them in sequence, you have to put all the audios in an Array or Dictionary of Audioclip.

You can then use a coroutine to play them sequentially and wait for each one to finish playing with `AudioSource.isPlaying` and also by yielding that coroutine function.

The example below uses the name of the audio files as the word to speak. You can change it around to use `Dictionary` if needed.

```
//All the Audios to play
public AudioClip[] speech;
public AudioSource auSource;

//Converts nae of audio to the index number
int findAudio(string audioName)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < speech.Length; i++)
    {
        if (speech[i].name == audioName)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

IEnumerator speak(string word)
{
    //Convert the string to the audioClip index 
    int audioIndex = findAudio(word);

    if (audioIndex != -1)
    {
        //Assign the clip to play
        auSource.clip = speech[audioIndex];

        //Play
        auSource.Play();

        //Wait until audio is done playing
        while (auSource.isPlaying)
        {
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}

IEnumerator PlayerSpeaker()
{
    yield return speak("Hello");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    yield return speak("Israel Abebe");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    yield return speak("How are you today?");

    yield return null;
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(PlayerSpeaker());
}
```